# Create Jumping Animation in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to create jumping animation from 2 sprites [image: 1] and[image: 2].
The animation can be illustrated like this[image]
When his position is at the highest value, he changes state. Then keep that state until he falls off and changes to idle state.
I have done the research, watched tutorials on youtube, and I found something called blend tree. Then I went to the [Unity documentation website](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-BlendTree.html) and my mind was spinning around and around, I just couldn't understand it. And is there any way to know when his position is at the highest value? or any solution to animate him? And when to use blend tree
And also, [a link to the tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xHargJbONls&t=563s)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would work with velocity conditions.
Let's say you start with an idle animation as default.
Then you make a transition from animation "idle" to animation "jumping" with the conditions `IsGrounded = false` to check if you're at the ground and `velocityY > 0` to check if you're jumping or not.

Then do another transition from "jumping" to "landing" with the conditions `IsGrounded = false` and `VelocityY < 0` so it checks if you're falling and will change the animation to the landing animation.

Comment: What is VelocityY? rigidbody2d.velocity.y, right ?

Comment: Yes you should check Rigidbody2D.velocity.y.

Comment: I am a little bit confused about Rigidbody2D.velocity.y. Does it mean the position of the player or the speed on the y axis?

Comment: You can see it as the "directional speed". When you jump your character gains velocity. If your character is falling down or not is determined by the velocity. Let's say you jump into the air in reallife. then you build up velocity. When you begin falling you fall, because you lost your velocity. There are simpler explanations but that should fit.

Comment: I found there is a problem, when I moved my character horizontally, the velocity.y changed so it didn'work, how can i solve it

Comment: I fixed it by adding a little bit difference to the condition but it didn't work

Comment: I found it, tks!